# How to reduce blockchain size on a production node?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I have a production Geth node whose blockchain occupies around ~600 GB. I'm trying to figure out how to free up disk space. I know I can remove the blockchain and start fast sync from scratch, but that will take some time (probably more than a day) and it is not acceptable for a production node that is expected to be up 24/7. I can bring it down but for a couple of hours at the most. So my question is how to reduce blockchain size with a minimal downtime?

I was considering starting a new Geth node in parallel and have it fully sync, and then migrate the keys from the old node to the new one. But is there a better approach?

Comment: Is this a private network or a public network?

Comment: Do you need to check account's historical balances of blocks below `lastblock-1000`? If not, you can prune the state and release 500GB of historical state entries.

Answer (score 2):

From [Issue #15797](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15797#issuecomment-357030043)

> Geth also supports "fast syncing" with itself, which you can use to
>   synchronize an existing chain into a fresh data directory and then
>   swap out the old one with the fresh one:
>
> ```
> geth --datadir=/my/temp/datadir copydb --cache=512 /my/main/datadir/geth/chaindata/
> rm -rf /my/main/datadir/geth/chaindata/
> mv /my/temp/datadir/geth/chaindata /my/main/datadir/geth/
> ```